# Trying to upvote giving orange notice box, then "forced?" logout and immediately logged in?

Tags: discussion, notifications, up-votes

I was trying to up-vote an answer, but every time I've pressed the arrow, an orange notification box appeared saying:

[image]

[Link to the answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11442834/352449)

---

I've kept trying for like 5 times, then out of the blue, I'm logged out!

A couple of seconds later I'm logged in! Tried again, and voila! the up-vote goes through.

**So, I'm wondering:**

- What happened here?
- What does this message means?
- I was logged out earlier, but my browser wasn't aware of it and this box did in fact appeared with a reason, perhaps because I couldn't vote?
- [Was a deployment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6791/184576)

---

This happened using Firefox 13.0.1 under Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: If it's fixed now and you can't reproduce it: does it really *matter* what happened?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @DiscountGucciHandbags Just trying to understand, at the very least it's a weird behaviour that never happened to me! ps: I'm a "every question has a response" / "every behaviour has a justification" kind of guy :)

Comment: @nhahtdh Using Firefox 13.0.1 under Ubuntu 12.04.